# Zend_Auth different roles

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

I'm looking to create roles like user / admin on signup to different controllers. I'm looking for official methods of it.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the Zend_ACL module. This is used for access control. You create roles and resources and map the roles to the resources.

Comment: thanks I just defined roles properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good tuts here:

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/165-Login-and-Authentication-with-Zend-Framework.html

http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/